# Apache Virtual Host not accessible from local network

Tags: apache, virtualhost, local-network

I have setup a Virtual Host with Apache2 with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It is possible to access the website from the outside.

```
example.com
```

But if I enter `example.com` from another system in my local network, it opens my router configuration page.

I forwarded my routers port 80 to my servers port 8080 in my network.

But I would like to access the website as well from my other systems in the local network. Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to try posting this question to Server Fault instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router probably does not support "NAT loopback", where you access a service on the local network via the WAN IP of the router. Most consumer grade routers do not support *NAT loopback*.

You only have 2 options:

1. Change your router to one that does support "NAT loopback".
   eg. [Which NETGEAR routers support NAT loopback](https://kb.netgear.com/000049578/Which-NETGEAR-routers-support-NAT-loopback)
2. Access your service via the internal IP address instead. You can override the public DNS using your local HOSTS file.

The way I generally "work around" this and have the site accessible to all machines/devices on the LAN, is to define a `local` *subdomain* (`A` record) in the public DNS that points to the local IP address. So when on the LAN I access the site by the subdomain `local.example.com` instead.

Related question on Security SE, which goes into more detail about what actually goes on with the network traffic:

- [Is NAT Loopback on my router a security problem?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/is-nat-loopback-on-my-router-a-security-problem)

Comment: Thank you so much for your very perfect answer! I did not know about "NAT loopback". I just did what you recommended: added an A record subdomain, which is now home.example.com pointing to the local IP address of my Apache Server (in my case 192.168.x.x). It took 5 minutes until it was active and now I can access home.example.com from the PCs in my local network. Thank you so much!